# Push_back faster than insert?

Tags: c++, performance, stl

I'm using `std::deque`. I was sure that substituting a loop with a `push_back` with a single `insert` would yield an increase in performance. It is also recommended, for instance [here](https://pkisensee.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/efficient-stl-insertion-tip-of-the-month/).

But now I'm not so sure anymore.

I've run some benchmarks on test code.

Main.cpp:

```
#include"queueInsert.h"

#include<Windows.h>

std::deque<int> queue;

constexpr size_t len = 64;

int arr[len];

int main()
{
    DWORD startTime = GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        insert(queue, arr, len);
    }
    DWORD endTime = GetTickCount();

    return endTime - startTime;
}
```

queueInsert.h:

```
#include<deque>

void insert(std::deque<int>&, int* arr, int n);
```

queueInsert.cpp -push version

```
#include "queueInsert.h"

void insert(std::deque<int>& queue, int* arr, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        queue.push_back(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

queueInsert.cpp -insert version

```
#include "queueInsert.h"

void insert(std::deque<int>& queue, int* arr, int n)
{
    queue.insert(queue.end(), arr, arr + n);
}
```

I get `203` milliseconds with `push_back`, but `218` with `insert`.

Changing `len` to `6`, and increasing the iterations to one million, keeps the same result: `219` mills for `push` and `266` for `insert`.

Only with `len = 640` does `push` lose out, and even then by very little: `1531` for `push` against `1437` for `insert`.

I'm compiling in Release in VisualStudio 2015 under Windows 10.

I'm sure the compiler isn't doing optimizations as inlining the constant number of iterations or fusing the loops, as every time i change the implementation only `queueInsert.cpp` is recompiled.

Am i doing profiling wrong? Or should I actually keep `push_back` if the amount of elements to be inserted isn't likely to be big?

Comment: *I'm sure the compiler isn't doing optimizations* -- Let's see the assembly listing.

Comment: "*Or should I actually keep push_back if the amount of elements to be inserted isn't likely to be big?*" Considering how trivial the performance difference is in this case, do whatever makes your code seem the most reasonable.

Comment: The article is from 2011.

Comment: You are measuring milliseconds using GetTickCount() which is accurate to 10-15 ms.  QueryPerformanceFrequency()/QueryPerformanceCounter() will provide greater resolution.

Answer (score 13):

`deque::insert` effectively has 3 possible ways of operating: general insert, insert in front, insert in back. Because of that, every time you call `insert`, it must do a test to see which way it needs to insert. So it has to test the iterator you pass against the front and the back.

`deque::push_back` has only 1 mode of operation: insert in back.

The advantage of using a bulk insert operation is that the container can detect exactly how much memory it needs to allocate to perform the whole insertion, since it can get the length of the iterator range. So the larger the bulk insert, the better `insert` will be.

Well, the better for **`vector`** at least.

See with `vector`, if you insert 30,000 elements one at a time, you're likely to perform reallocation ~14-15 times. That means allocating new memory and copying the old data into that memory. Whereas if you insert 30,000 elements all at once, you get a *single* reallocation.

`deque` is typically implemented as an array of fixed-size blocks. Because of that, if you insert 30,000 elements one at a time, you will get ~3,000 allocations (depending on the block size). If you insert 30,000 elements all at once, you will get... ~3,000 allocations. So you're not really saving much.

Since bulk insert isn't much different from single insert for `deque`, what happens is a fight between micro-optimization issues. Every `insert` call has to do iterator comparison to see how to perform that insertion. As such, the smaller the insertions, the less efficient `insert` will be. `push_back` doesn't have that overhead, but it is a function call for each element. So it has that overhead.

Therefore, `insert` will likely win when the number of elements added per insert is high.

Comment: I thought of it, but concluded it couldn't be that significant, being a single check over as much as `64` elements. However, I agree this is the most likely explanation at the moment.